# Multiple Alarm fire at same time

Tags: android

i have a problem with triggering the multiple alarm at first time , here is my code

it is launcher activity where i write the following code ::

**onCreate Method :

```
// Calling Method setNextAlarm two times..with different id and time 

    setNextAlarm(0,60000);
    setNextAlarm(1,120000);
```

and the setNextAlarm is here ::

```
    private void setNextAlarm(int id,long time) {
            AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) TestAct.this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(TestAct.this, OnBootReceiver.class);
            i.putExtra("id", id);

            Log.e("Firing up next alarm in "+id,""+time/(60*1000) +"minutes");

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TestAct.this, id, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            mgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, pi);
   }
```

when i run this code it calls the onBootReceiver which is our Broadcast receiver class.

**So My question is ::**

After defining the different time and id in this method

```
setNextAlarm(0,60000);
setNextAlarm(1,120000);
```

**why it fires at same time ? Except the first time it runs fine at fixed interval.**

this is my onBootReceiver class's onReceive method

```
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();  

int id = b.getInt("id");

if(id==1){
    PERIOD=300000;
}else{
    PERIOD=120000;
}

Log.e("OnBootReceiver"," Calling"+id+" in "+PERIOD/60000 + "minutes");

AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
   i.putExtra("id", id);
   PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id,i, 0);
   mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                      SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                      PERIOD,
                      pi);
```

Thanks.

Comment: On boot receiver, for id 0, period becomes 120000 same as the id 1. am I wrong?

Comment: your are  right .. for id 0 period becomes 120000 for id 1 period is 300000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in  OnBootReceiver

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, PERIOD, pi);
```

here is change

i set

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000  for id = 0
```

and set the

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 120000  for id = 1
```

and the problem resolved.

**But i am still waiting for Better Explanation.**

i found little information here about **SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()**

elapsedRealtime() is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted, including deep sleep. This clock should be used when measuring time intervals that may span periods of system sleep.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html