# How to set Multiple daily alarm?

Tags: android

I want to set more than one daily alarm in my android application for that I am making demo code like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 30000, pi);
```

I has given 30000 ms as a interval, so I think it should be repeat every 30 second. but not repeating. its ringing once after 1 min from I started the app is I am wrong ? and what should I do to set multiple daily alarm in My application ?
Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this question may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921189/multiple-alarm-fire-at-same-time/9923848#9923848

Comment: you can also visit this site for basic idea http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/1.5_r4/com/android/alarmclock/Alarms.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in your `PendingIntent` with the flag `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, so with this you can only set your alarm once. If you want repeating alarm, try using the flag `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html